# Laravel markdown mail vs blade templating

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

In laravel, new markdown feature for mailing provides some components to customize mail. I like them. They are cool but how are they different from blade layout as long as I can do the same with normal blade layout.

Comment: I guess that the markdown is useful for emails which are created by non-developers through a Markdown editor.

Comment: How can a non-developer even know that a blade file will need to be edited? Does it make sense?

Comment: You can insert markdown from the database in to a blade/markdown file with ```{!! $markdown !!}``` right? Or maybe I'm not entirely understanding the question.

Comment: Never mind.
I was just asking in details.
I understand what you said. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Markdown email gives you a simplified syntax compared to HTML. For example:

- instead of wrapping headings in `h1`, `h2`, etc. tags, you can just put a `#`, `##`, etc. at the beginning of the line
- no need to wrap lists in `<ul>`, and list items in `<li>` tags. In markdown, you can just use a dash (`-`) for listing elements
- italic/bold font can be achieved by putting `*`/`**` around the text you want to emphasize

The above, [and other features of markdown](https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet) can make your templates more readable.

Comment: Is there any performance concerns while rendering/compiling view vs markdown emails ?

Comment: Not really - markdown, or not, the views are cached anyway.